# overflow blocks my tooltip from showing out of the box

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I been trying for over a week to figure out how to make a tool tip break out of a box with overflow parent in it. but no matter what solution I try it just get trapped inside the box. in the following code pen is an example . I want each icon to pop up  a tool-tip on hover . but if the icon on the right close to the scroll bar pop up for example a tool tip with very long content inside of it it just won't go out of the box to show it all , but instead half of the tool tip is appearing . I give on making it it in CSS and  I'm thinking is there any possible solution using java script ?

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/digi-ralph/pen/GRNQjLg)

```css
.list {
    margin:50px auto;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0.6em;
    overflow: hidden auto;
    height: 55vh;
    background:#1e212d;
    color:#fff;
    .tab-title {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        .flex-tab {
                padding: 0 10px;
                margin-top: 0.5em;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: flex-start;
            .flex {
                    cursor: pointer;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    margin: 0.3em 0.1em;
                    &:hover,&:focus-within {
                    background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
                    
                    }
                .icon {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                    width: 30px;
                    height: 30px;
                    .img { 
                        width: 80%;
                        height: 80%;
                    }   
                }  
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test1.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="list">
    <div class="set">
        <!-- RESULT -->
        <div class="tab-title" id="act">
            <div class="nav">Result</div>
            <div class="flex-tab" id="recent">
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
                <!-- START -->
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="icon" data-tooltip="stars">
                        <img class="img"
                            src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/batman-icon-jira-avatar-11562897771zvwv8r510z.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END  -->
            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: fixed the link sorry ..